# Для какой платформы в первую очередь создать мессенджер?

Tags: кроссплатформенность

Я хочу создать свой мессенджер. Но появился вопрос: под какую платформу создать его в первую очередь? Веб-сайт, ПК или для мобильных устройств?

Заранее извиняюсь за возможно глупый вопрос, но я просто первый раз создаю действительно крупный проект.

Comment: Только вы можете дать ответ на этот вопрос, так как никто кроме вас не знает вашу целевую аудиторию.

Comment: Целевая аудитория: Россия

Comment: И для всех возрастов

Comment: Под консоль (+апи) а дальше, если взлетит, люди сами напишут.

Comment: @KoVadim с джаббером и матриксом такое не прокатило

Comment: Потому я и написал "если". Потому что нужна роскрутка

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Советую сначала создать web приложение (для кроссплатформенности), а потом уже при необходимости делать приложения на устройства. Хотя это конечно зависит от назначения вашего мессенджера и предполагаемой аудитории, так что Вам лучше знать.

Comment: Спасибо большое!